# Weak Derivative of a Function

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I am working on fundamental solutions and I need to solve the distributional/weak derivative of the following which I have written in the formula for weak derivative,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}(sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi)\varphi''(x)\,dx$ $\,$-$\,$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{k}(sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi)\varphi(x)\,dx$

The above integral should equal the test function $\varphi(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(x-\xi)\varphi(x)\,dx$. Ive made it so far as to split the first term into two parts,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\xi}\frac{1}{k}(sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi)\varphi''(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{\xi}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}(sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi)\varphi''(x)\,dx$

and for each term I'm trying integration by parts where

$u=sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi),\,du=sin(k(x-\xi))\delta(x-\xi)\,+\,2H(x-\xi)cos(k(x-\xi))\,dx$

$v=\varphi'(x)\,,\,dv=\varphi''(x)\,dx$

From here, I'm only making the integration by parts worse for the other terms, can anyone help me in helping solve this integration... thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, H(x-\xi) \, dx = \int_{\xi}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's part of the calculations. You can probably complete it yourself:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}(\sin(k(x-\xi))H(x-\xi)\varphi''(x)\,dx
=\int_{\xi}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}(\sin(k(x-\xi))\varphi''(x)\,dx \\
= \left[\frac{1}{k}(\sin(k(x-\xi))\varphi'(x)\right]_{\xi}^{\infty} - \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(\cos(k(x-\xi))\varphi'(x)\,dx \\
= -\frac{1}{k}(\sin(k(\xi-\xi))\varphi'(\xi) - \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(\cos(k(x-\xi))\varphi'(x)\,dx \\
= - \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(\cos(k(x-\xi))\varphi'(x)\,dx \\
= -\left[(\cos(k(x-\xi))\varphi(x)\right]_{\xi}^{\infty} + \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(-k\sin(k(x-\xi))\varphi(x)\,dx \\
= (\cos(k(\xi-\xi))\varphi(\xi) - k \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(\sin(k(x-\xi))\varphi(x)\,dx \\
= \varphi(\xi) - k \int_{\xi}^{\infty}(\sin(k(x-\xi))\varphi(x)\,dx \\
$$